Read position of vertices that were displaced by shader (Shader graph)
So I have a shader that creates terrain from chunks, the shader was made using shader graph, now i need to instantiate some objects on the terrain, my general idea was to take a random vertex of a chunk, get it's global coordinates.
Then I realized that shader displaces vertices on GPU, but instantiating is done on CPU side, i thought i could use GPU readbacks, but i didn't quite get how to use it, is it really possible to do with shader graph.
I also thought of just transfering the displacement logic from shader to cs script, but i couldn't get it to be tileable.
So, if the idea somehow read data from GPU sounds bad, it would be great to get some solutions about tileable noise displacement.
Here is what i tried for displacing via cs file. Every object that had that script attached had the same displacement, not tileable.
for (int i = 0; i < originalVertices.Length; i++)
{
    Vector3 vertexWorldPos = transform.TransformPoint(transform.position) + originalVertices[i];
    displacedVertices[i] = vertexWorldPos;
    displacedVertices[i].y = Mathf.PerlinNoise(vertexWorldPos.x * noiseScale, vertexWorldPos.z + noiseScale) * Height;
    Debug.Log(displacedVertices[i]);
}
mesh.vertices = displacedVertices;
mesh.RecalculateNormals(); // Recalculate normals to ensure lighting is correct


shader gaph doesn't support compute buffer - otherwise I would have suggested to use that for the calculation but do the mesh creation on c#/CPU side ... which is probably something you could do if you switch to a text based compute shader instead
